# Path Wont Close JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a "custom shape" and for some reason the fill doesn't show up which im assuming means it isn't closed. Anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
    Path path = new Path();

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0, 0));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(5, 0));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(5, 0));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(5, 4));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(5, 4));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(15, 4));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(15, 4));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(15, 0));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(15, 0));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(18, 0));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(18, 0));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(18, 4));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(18, 4));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(20, 4));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(20, 4));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(20, 6));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(20, 6));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0, 6));

    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0, 6));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0, 0));

    path.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    path.relocate(250, 250);

    root.getChildren().add(path);
    root.setScaleX(10);
    root.setScaleY(10);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `MoveTo` after a `LineTo` to the same position. Furthermore you should close the path using `ClosePath` instead of adding a `LineTo`:

```
path.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(0, 0),
                          new LineTo(5, 0),
                          new LineTo(5, 4),
                          new LineTo(15, 4),
                          new LineTo(15, 0),
                          new LineTo(18, 0),
                          new LineTo(18, 4),
                          new LineTo(20, 4),
                          new LineTo(20, 6),
                          new LineTo(0, 6),
                          new ClosePath());
```